# How to update a canvas in SWT every 100 milliseconds inside a KeyListener Java

Tags: java, canvas, swt, sleep, redraw

I'm writing a program which updates a canvas after every key press by regenerating a data structure (cube) and then painting this onto the canvas. If the user enters 'S' I want the canvas to display the cube after every turn (turn = one character of the solution string generated by the program) every 100ms and redraw this to the screen, have tried several different approaches but can't get it to work. This is my KeyListener code:

```
canvas.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            GC gc = new GC(canvas);
            Rectangle rect = canvas.getClientArea();


            String alg = ""+e.character;

            cube.performAlgorithm(alg, false);

            drawCube(rect,gc);

            if(e.character=='S'){
                Cube cube2 = new Cube(cube);
                String solution = Solutions.longsolve(cube2, "Fridrich", false);

                String[] moves = new String[solution.length()];

                moves = solution.split("(?!^)");

                for(String move : moves){
                    cube.performAlgorithm(move, false);

                    try {
                        drawCube(rect,gc);
                        canvas.redraw();
                        canvas.update();
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }





                }
                //System.out.println(solution);

            }
            gc.dispose();

        }
    });
```

and my drawFace and drawCube code, appreciate this may not be a very nice way of solving my problem but I'm very new to using SWT.

```
private static void drawFace(GC gc, int startwidth, int startdepth, int celldim, Color[] colour, byte[][] Face){
    gc.setForeground(gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

    int x = startwidth;
    int y = startdepth;

    //draw face of the cube
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, celldim, celldim);
            gc.setBackground(colour[Face[i][j]]);
            gc.fillRectangle(rect);
            gc.drawRectangle(rect);

            x += celldim;
            //only draw a box
        }
        x = startwidth;
        y+=celldim;
    }
}

private static void drawCube(Rectangle clientArea, GC gc){
    int startdepth = 10;

    int celldim = (((clientArea.height)-(startdepth*2))/12);
    int startwidth =  (int) ((int)(clientArea.width/2)-(1.5*celldim));

    Color[] colours = {gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN),gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED),
            gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE),gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY),
            gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK),gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW)};

    gc.setForeground(gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

    int x = startwidth;
    int y = startdepth;

    drawFace(gc, x, y, celldim,colours,cube.Uface);
    y += (3*celldim);
    drawFace(gc, x, y, celldim,colours,cube.Fface);
    x -= (3*celldim);
    drawFace(gc, x, y, celldim,colours,cube.Lface);
    x += (6*celldim);
    drawFace(gc, x, y, celldim,colours,cube.Rface);
    x -= (3*celldim);
    y += (3*celldim);
    drawFace(gc, x, y, celldim,colours,cube.Dface);
    y += (3*celldim);
    drawFace(gc, x, y, celldim,colours,cube.Bface);
}
```

Comment: Currently it executes the whole for loop, sleeping and all, but without updating the canvas and then just redraws it after it's finished (so with none of the intermediary steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do updates in a loop like that because you must let the main SWT `Display.readAndDispatch` loop run since this is what actually updates the screen.

Instead use `Display.timerExec` to execute one step of the loop every 100ms:

```
Display.getDefault().timerExec(100, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      canvas.redraw();

      // Run again - TODO add logic to stop after correct number of moves
      Display.getDefault().timerExec(100, this);
    }
   });
```

You should just call `redraw` in this routine, all the actual drawing should be in a paint listener on the control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so can this Display.timerExec go inside my key listener?

Comment: Yes, you can call it in the listener.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother again, but I tried this, but still with no luck, it still performs the full solve then redraws the cube. i.e. doesn't update move by move. I tried it with the additional line Display.getDefault().timerExec(1000,this); but this caused same thing to happen and then was in an infinite loop after.
for(String move : moves){
 Display.getDefault().timerExec(1000, new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run(){
  GC gc = new GC(canvas);
  cube.performAlgorithm(move, false);
  drawCube(rect,gc);
  canvas.redraw();
  System.out.println(move);
 }
});
      
}

Comment: You call timerExec **once** in the keylistener. When the delayed code runs you call it again at the end until the number of moves has been done - you will have to add code to my example to track the number of moves. I also told you only to do a `redraw`. You **must** use a PaintListener to do the actual painting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, have got it working now!